# QPixmap не работает с изображением формата jpg

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, изображения, pixmap

Хотел вывести изображение в формате jpg, но вместо этого ничего не произошло. Однако программа работает с форматом png.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow



class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(400, 400, 400, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('Отображение картинки')
        self.pixmap = QPixmap('orig.jpg')
        self.image = QLabel(self)
        self.image.move(80, 60)
        self.image.resize(250, 250)
        self.image.setPixmap(self.pixmap)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Я хочу открыть фотографию 'orig.jpg', но вместо этого ничего не происходит, однако если я попытаюсь открыть картинку в формате png ('car.png'), то все работает.

orig.jpg:

[image: Изображение 'orig.jpg']

Список плагинов:

```
qfig.dll
qicns.dll
qico.dll
qjpeg.dll
qsvg.dll
qtga.dll
qtiff.dll
qwbmp.dll
```

Да, здесь есть `qjpeg.dll`, но почему-то не работает.

`print(QImageReader.supportedImageFormats())` выдало

> [PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'bmp'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'pbm'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'pgm'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'png'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'ppm'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'xbm'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'xpm')]
>
> **Получается, там нет b'jpg'**

Comment: Скорее всего, плагин картинки для jpg (он в виде DLL) или отсутствует, или по какой-то причине не подтянулся (так то, по моему, он устанавливается вместе с pyqt5). Попробуйте вывести список доступных форматов через https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimagereader.html#supportedImageFormats `QimageReader.supportedImageFormats()` и написать какие вывело

Comment: А плагины можно посмотреть в папке питона, у меня, например, такой путь `C:\Users\ipetrash\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats` и там есть плагин для jpg -- `qjpeg.dll`. PS. пример использования `supportedImageFormats`: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/90657c856904ab110241a9ca5615438d3dd1d03d/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/QImageReader.supportedImageFormats.py#L10

Comment: опубликуйте пожалуйста изображение (`orig.jpg`), с которым у вас воpникают проблемы.

Comment: Добавил сверху. Почему-то не получилось сразу снизу, извините

Comment: Ни одна .jpg фотография не загружалась. Не только эта.

Comment: А как вы запускаете скрипт? Через IDE или консоль? Мб переустановить pyqt5? Или попробовать запустить скрипт с `supportedImageFormats` через консоль, если до этого запускали в IDE или наоборот? Еще возможен вариант ручного указания библиотек pyqt5, но, это крайний вариант, делал такое для pyqt4, думаю, не сложно будет вам адаптировать для pyqt5: https://github.com/gil9red/telegram__url2image_bot/blob/41ed147aaa34eda38a330402f6333daa5ec157c5/url2image.py#L29

Comment: Через IDE. Хорошо, попробую ваши варианты

Comment: какой результат при запуске приложения через консоль/терминал/CMD ?

Comment: Я попробовал `print(QImageReader.supportedImageFormats())` в консоли. И результат тот же - там нет 'jpg'

Comment: Простите, небольшой вопрос по поводу `qApp = PyQt4.QtGui.QApplication.instance()` Я заменил `PyQt4` на `PyQt5`, чтобы получилось `qApp = PyQt5.QtGui.QApplication.instance()` и встретил `module 'PyQt5.QtGui' has no attribute 'QApplication''`

Comment: Попробую лучше переустановить PyQt5

Comment: Что со мной не так? Переустановил PyQt5, PyQt5.tools и все равно не работает, к тому же `print(QImageReader.supportedImageFormats())` все еще не выводит `b'jpg'` в своем списке

Comment: Ладно, это бесполезно. Куча таких же вопросов в интернете. Кому-то что-то помогло, кому-то нет. Спасибо большое за ваше старание. Отложу этот вопрос на потом и спрошу опытного друга на прямую в жизни.

Comment: @BroadCaster, пишите в комментарии ник с `@`, а то уведомление о комментарии не приходит :) В `Qt5` класс `QApplication` переехал из `QtGui` в `QtWidgets`. Удачи с этим вопросом, такое действительно лучше в живую разбирать. Когда разберетесь, напиши тут в ответе, что вам помогло :) А так... мб тут еще проблема с версией python, например, попробовать на версии постарше, типа, 3.7. Кст, вы не ответили, у вас те DLL плагинов есть в папке питона в `site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats`?

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо, не знал про @ ). Я попробовал заменить строчку `qApp = PyQt5.QtGui.QApplication.instance()` на `qApp = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()` и встретил другую ошибку - `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'addLibraryPath'` из строчки `qApp.addLibraryPath(plugins_dir)`. Список плагинов DLL я написал в самом вопросе, можете посмотреть. Вот они:
`qfig.dll
qicns.dll
qico.dll
qjpeg.dll
qsvg.dll
qtga.dll
qtiff.dll
qwbmp.dll`
Когда удастся разобраться, обязательно напишу здесь, а пока я просто работаю с расширением "png" и конвертирую в него, если надо.

Comment: Похоже, `QApplication.instance()` вернул `None` потому что до вызова его не был создан `QApplication`

Comment: напишите пожалуйста, как решили проблему, у самого тоже самое

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл решение:

Вы должны перейти в папку где ваш питон. У меня путь туда такой: `C:\Users\Я\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39` потом в `Lib` оттуда в `site-packages` потом в `PyQt5` и оттуда либо в `Qt` либо в `Qt5`.

В одной из этих папок лежит папка `plugins` (у меня это `Qt5`) и в этой папке лежит папка `imageformats` вы её копируете возвращаетесь в папку где питон лежит (`C:\Users\Я\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39`) и вставляете этот `imageformats` прямо туда.